# Scroll to a position on scroll down and another on scroll up event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know if I'm doing it right but I want to scroll to the next div when the user scroll down and scroll to the previous div in the page when the user scroll up.
First of all I do this to test the scroll event and the animation of scrolling :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 1000
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

That's just a test but it work well.
Now, I want to differentiate the scroll down and the scroll up event to scroll to the next or the previous div so I search and I found some solutions like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var newPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(lastPosition - newPosition > 0){
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 1000
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work...
I think the method to get the scroll down or the scroll up doesn't work in my case.
Do you have any solution to do this or maybe an alternative ?
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like that script is relying on fixed positioning. There's way too many different screen sizes and resolutions to ever make that reliable except maybe for yourself only. I'd just rely on [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Is [something like this](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1) close to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you !
Sorry, I search but without the exact term it's difficult to found some informations about it.
I was looking to something like this but this one use some different method :
https://www.raoul-gaillard.com/work

Answer (score 0):

> In your case, the **height** of the **body** or your **container** should be set to the **window height** and the **overflow** of that should be set to **hidden**, because you want to scroll to the target Div by javascript.
>
> by setting the **overflow: hidden** on the **body** or your **container**, you **prevent**
>   the window from scrolling on the page.

```
body {
    background: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

> The next step is detecting the scrolling direction (Up/Down). You can
>   check it by the **deltaY** property of the scroll event.
>
> Finally, get the next or previous Div and scroll to it.
>   **The complete example is** [here](http://hamidjavadi.com/examples/div-scroll-animation.html)

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {

    var deltaY = event.originalEvent.deltaY || event.deltaY;

    if (deltaY > 0) { 

    // Scrolled to Down: Next Div

    } else if (deltaY < 0) {  

    // Scrolled to Up: Previous Div

    }

});
```

> You can see the completed code here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: #eee;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .section {
                height: 600px;
            }

            .section.active {
                background: #ccc;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="active section">Section 1</div>
        <div class="section">Section 2</div>
        <div class="section">Section 3</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(event) {

                var deltaY = event.originalEvent.deltaY || event.deltaY,
                    $activeSection = $('.section.active'),
                    $container = $('body'),
                    containerOffset = $container[0].offsetTop,
                    $targetSection = null,
                    mustBeScroll = false;

                if(deltaY > 0) { // Scrolled to Down: Next Div

                    if($activeSection.next('.section').length > 0) {
                        $targetSection = $activeSection.next('.section');
                        mustBeScroll = true;
                    }

                } else if (deltaY < 0) {  // Scrolled to Up: Previous Div

                    if ($activeSection.prev('.section').length > 0) {
                        $targetSection = $activeSection.prev('.section');
                        mustBeScroll = true;
                    }

                }

                if(mustBeScroll == true) {

                    $container.stop(false, true).animate({ scrollTop : $targetSection[0].offsetTop - containerOffset }, 500);

                    // Change background color
                    $activeSection.removeClass('active');
                    $targetSection.addClass('active');

                }

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm a beginner so I don't understand all your code but thank you, it allowed me to understand a little better how to do, i keep searching a solution.

Comment: Any question? Ask me

Comment: I dont know why but your code dont work for me, the active section dont change on scroll, maybe you have an idea ?

Comment: Can you share your code? I need to see your code to find the problem.

Comment: I don't know if for you it's working but the exemple you share don't work for me

Comment: May your code has an error. I can't help you without seeing your code. Check the console log to see errors. You can see my code live version here: http://hamidjavadi.com/examples/div-scroll-animation.html

Comment: Where did you see the live version? Mobile or PC? it is working on the mouse wheel event.